# React Native - how can i share a message in bold font weight?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native Share API and I want to share a message in bold font weight
I can not seem to find a way to do it
Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: Can you please post the code of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found anything about sharing bold text, but you can use the already assigned bold characters found in the Unicode characters here:

https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1D400.html

I made this function that transforms characters to bold using this method:

```
const toBold = text =>{
  const charSet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '?', '.', ',', '"', "'"];
  const targetCharSet = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '❗', '❓', '.', ',', '"', "'"];
  const textArray = text.split('');
  let boldText = '';
  textArray.forEach((letter) => {
    const index = charSet.findIndex((_letter) => _letter === letter);
    if (index !== -1) {
      boldText = boldText + targetCharSet[index];
    } else {
      boldText = boldText + letter;
    }
  });
  return boldText;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
toBold('Hi Mom');
```

**Output:**

**Note:**
The text might not show up in your console.

Comment: this was useful for me